# How does this js array works?

Tags: javascript, arrays

i've got a question :

here is the code :

```
    var arr = [
[1,2,3],
[4,5,6],
[7,8,9],
[[10,11,12], 13, 14]
```

];

```
arr[3]; // equals [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
arr[3][0]; // equals [10,11,12]
arr[3][0][1]; // equals 11
```

how the "arr[3]", "arr[3] [0]" and "arr[3] [0] [1]" actually work ?

ps : i'm new on Stack Overflow, i can't get why people left me -2.

Comment: Do you understand what array is? If so you should understand how `a[1]` works if `a = [1,2,3]`. Only `2` can be another array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In programming arrays have a zero based index, this means we do not start counting from 1 but from 0.

If you want to grab the first array then you have to access index 0 `arr[0]`.

```js
var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
];

function showArray()
{
    console.info(arr[0]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showArray()">Show</button>
```

If you want to grab the second array then you have to access index 1 `arr[1]`.

```js
var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
];

function showArray()
{
    console.info(arr[1]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showArray()">Show</button>
```

If you want to grab the 1th array of the 4th array then you first have to access index 3 `arr[3]` then of this array select index 0 `arr[3][0]`

```js
var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
];

function showArray()
{
    console.info(arr[3][0]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showArray()">Show</button>
```

If you want to grab the 1th value of the 1th array of the 4th array (which is 10) then you first have to access index 3 `arr[3]` then of this array select index 0 `arr[3][0]` then select index 0 of that array `arr[3][0][0]`.

```js
var arr = [
    [1,2,3],
    [4,5,6],
    [7,8,9],
    [[10,11,12], 13, 14]
];

function showArray()
{
    console.info(arr[3][0][0]);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="showArray()">Show</button>
```